# Windows 7's showing "Date" in a folder can cause confusions and what can be done about it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I found that Windows 7 uses "Date" instead of "Date modified" in some folders, such as the "Pictures" folder.

So initially, I thought they are the same, but until later, when I know some files were modified last night, but if I arrange the files by "Date", I don't see those files...  (there are close to 100 files in this folder, and the view is "Details" -- as a list)

So I thought this is a bug with Windows 7, with all those files missing.  Refreshing the folder didn't work.  Until finally, it seems that the "Date" is the "Date created"... so that's why the modified files didn't show up near the top of the list.  The creation date was much earlier.

This caused quite some confusion.  I wonder if there is any way to make all folders show "Date modified" instead of "Date" instead -- one simple step for all folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite one step, but if you go into Details view you can right click on the header and get a context menu.

By default "Date" is checked, but "Date Created" and "Date Modified" are present but unchecked. So uncheck "Date" and check "Date Modified".

This will apply to all the pictures folders.

I think the "Date" as "Date Created" only applies to the Pictures library. My Documents library has "Date Modified". Perhaps the thinking is that most users won't be editing their photos so sorting by date modified would be the same as date created. However, as I don't work for Microsoft that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't view data modified at all in a Pictures folder. You have to change the folder type to documents or General Items, and then you have the option to show date modified. windows 7 has so many flaws and even bugs in Explorer - especially the search feature which lacks the control and options that XP had. Plus it will often slow down such that it will take many minutes to search for a name in a folder with only a few files. I've never had so much trouble with an operating system.